# DownloadManager throw exception when downloading more then one file

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I want to download 2 files from my server, If I en queue one file everything goes smoothly, with two files the download manager throws me this exception

```
W/DownloadManager﹕ Exception for id 126: Http Range request failure: totalBytes = 5424932, bytes recvd so far: 5424932
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Http Range request failure: totalBytes = 5424932, bytes recvd so far: 5424932
        at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadThread.handleOtherStatus(DownloadThread.java:735)
        at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadThread.handleExceptionalStatus(DownloadThread.java:724)
        at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadThread.executeDownload(DownloadThread.java:289)
        at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadThread.run(DownloadThread.java:203)
```

this happens at the end of the file downloading, it completes, throws this exception and not placing it on the external storage, then the second file being downloaded just fine.

this is the simple code: (the url's are fine)

```
  for (String url : urls)
    {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, parseFileNameFromURL(url));
        request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
        ((DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE)).enqueue(request);
    }
```